# Since latest update, Laptop screen turns to statics (all the screen pixels flash randomly) and PC freeze when Ubuntu screen saver starts

Tags: 20.04, screen, screensaver

I have Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on an Asus Laptop with AMD cpu and AMD graphic card, and since the latest automatic updates received on 21/01/2022, my laptop basically crashes (the screen turns to statics, like flickering snow, and I haven't found a way to return to normal other than turn off / turn on the laptop) every time the Ubuntu screen saving feature starts.

Here are the 3 updates received :

```
Start-Date: 2022-01-21  06:07:14
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: vim-common:amd64 (2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.4, 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.6), vim-tiny:amd64 (2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.4, 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.6)
End-Date: 2022-01-21  06:07:17

Start-Date: 2022-01-21  06:07:19
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xxd:amd64 (2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.4, 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.6)
End-Date: 2022-01-21  06:07:21

Start-Date: 2022-01-21  06:49:15
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.1919'
Upgrade: ubuntu-advantage-tools:amd64 (27.4.2~20.04.1, 27.5~20.04.1), gdb:amd64 (9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04, 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), gdbserver:amd64 (9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04, 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), linux-firmware:amd64 (1.187.24, 1.187.25)
End-Date: 2022-01-21  06:50:48
```

As a workaround, I've disabled it (set it to "never" on the setting where they ask how long should the black screen starts) but I would prefer a real solution to avoid to have to keep the screen on all the time.

Here are the last lines of my journals when I reproduced the issue a few minutes ago :

**SYSTEM**

```
05:04:55 kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1642824295.891:75): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=2324 comm="pool-org.gnome." exe="/snap/snap-store/558/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=93 compat=0 ip=0x7f0104b444fb code=0x50000
05:04:53 kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
05:04:53 kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
05:04:53 kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
05:04:50 kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
05:04:48 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1642824288.175:72): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/PackageKit/Vendor.conf" pid=2324 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
05:04:46 kernel: wlp1s0: associated
05:04:46 kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1642824286.231:67): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=2324 comm="snap-store" exe="/snap/snap-store/558/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7f0104b4d89d code=0x50000
05:04:44 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 54 callbacks suppressed
05:04:44 kernel: rfkill: input handler disabled
05:04:43 kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
05:04:41 kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
```

**APPLICATIONS**

```
05:05:53 gnome-software: automatically prevented from changing kind on system/snap/*/desktop/io.snapcraft.snapd-PMrrV4ml8uWuEUDBT8dSGnKUYbevVhc4/latest/stable from desktop to unknown!
05:05:53 gnome-software: automatically prevented from changing kind on system/snap/*/desktop/io.snapcraft.snapd-PMrrV4ml8uWuEUDBT8dSGnKUYbevVhc4/latest/stable from desktop to unknown!
05:05:53 gnome-software: automatically prevented from changing kind on system/snap/*/runtime/io.snapcraft.core20-DLqre5XGLbDqg9jPtiAhRRjDuPVa5X1q/latest/stable from runtime to unknown!
05:05:52 gnome-software: automatically prevented from changing kind on system/snap/*/runtime/io.snapcraft.bare-EISPgh06mRh1vordZY9OZ34QHdd7OrdR/latest/stable from runtime to unknown!
05:05:51 gnome-software: automatically prevented from changing kind on system/snap/*/runtime/io.snapcraft.core18-CSO04Jhav2yK0uz97cr0ipQRyqg0qQL6/latest/stable from runtime to unknown!
05:05:47 gnome-software: lost session service
05:05:47 gnome-software: disabled plugins: dpkg, dummy, repos
05:05:47 gnome-software: enabled plugins: desktop-categories, fwupd, os-release, packagekit, packagekit-local, packagekit-offline, packagekit-proxy, packagekit-refine-repos, packagekit-refresh, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit-url-to-app, appstream, desktop-menu-path, flatpak, hardcoded-blacklist, modalias, packagekit-refine, rewrite-resource, snap, odrs, packagekit-history, provenance, systemd-updates, generic-updates, provenance-license, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
05:05:47 gnome-software: plugin appstream took 2,1 seconds to do setup
05:05:47 pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
05:05:46 gnome-software: xb_builder_node_unlink: assertion 'XB_IS_BUILDER_NODE (self)' failed
05:05:43 systemd: Started Virtual filesystem metadata service.
05:05:43 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1770] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
05:05:43 systemd: Starting Virtual filesystem metadata service...
05:05:43 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1770] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.service' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1000 pid=2047 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
```

**SECURITY**

```
05:05:53 gnome-software: automatically prevented from changing kind on system/snap/*/desktop/io.snapcraft.snapd-PMrrV4ml8uWuEUDBT8dSGnKUYbevVhc4/latest/stable from desktop to unknown!
05:05:53 gnome-software: automatically prevented from changing kind on system/snap/*/desktop/io.snapcraft.snapd-PMrrV4ml8uWuEUDBT8dSGnKUYbevVhc4/latest/stable from desktop to unknown!
05:05:53 gnome-software: automatically prevented from changing kind on system/snap/*/runtime/io.snapcraft.core20-DLqre5XGLbDqg9jPtiAhRRjDuPVa5X1q/latest/stable from runtime to unknown!
05:05:52 gnome-software: automatically prevented from changing kind on system/snap/*/runtime/io.snapcraft.bare-EISPgh06mRh1vordZY9OZ34QHdd7OrdR/latest/stable from runtime to unknown!
05:05:51 gnome-software: automatically prevented from changing kind on system/snap/*/runtime/io.snapcraft.core18-CSO04Jhav2yK0uz97cr0ipQRyqg0qQL6/latest/stable from runtime to unknown!
05:05:47 gnome-software: lost session service
05:05:47 gnome-software: disabled plugins: dpkg, dummy, repos
05:05:47 gnome-software: enabled plugins: desktop-categories, fwupd, os-release, packagekit, packagekit-local, packagekit-offline, packagekit-proxy, packagekit-refine-repos, packagekit-refresh, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit-url-to-app, appstream, desktop-menu-path, flatpak, hardcoded-blacklist, modalias, packagekit-refine, rewrite-resource, snap, odrs, packagekit-history, provenance, systemd-updates, generic-updates, provenance-license, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
05:05:47 gnome-software: plugin appstream took 2,1 seconds to do setup
05:05:47 pkexec: nolife4ever: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/nolife4ever] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
05:05:46 gnome-software: xb_builder_node_unlink: assertion 'XB_IS_BUILDER_NODE (self)' failed
05:05:43 systemd: Started Virtual filesystem metadata service.
05:05:43 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1770] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
05:05:43 systemd: Starting Virtual filesystem metadata service...
05:05:43 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1770] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.service' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1000 pid=2047 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
```

Hardware: nothing.

---

Problem 'solved' : I've just learn that Ubuntu 22 could be tested so I decided to try it... and this upgrade fixed my issue !
So, I guess it was a bug in the latest Ubuntu update I had received.
While I'm here : the upgrade worked well, not only it fixed my issue but it seems everything works well except a little utility I was using to display cpu / mem / hd infos on my desktop but it's most likely just a customization issue.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my post following your advices. But I'm too noob to be able to understand what is the issue so I hope it will be enough for others.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *jammy* jellyfish [22.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu-next) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site [expected release date for Ubuntu 22.04 is 21 April 2022](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906)) when your question will be on-topic here. *Also note Ubuntu products that use the year format are different to those that use the year.month format ie 20!=20.04*